# Selecting $p-1$ integers from a set of $p+1$ integers, so that their weighted sum is divisible by $p$.

Tags: combinatorics, prime-numbers, divisibility

An odd prime number $p$ and a $(p + 1)$-element set $S$ of integers are given.
Prove that it is possible to choose
distinct numbers $a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots, a_{p-1}\in S$ such that

\begin{equation}1\cdot a_1+2\cdot a_2+\cdots + (p-1)a_{p-1} \end{equation}

is a multiple of p.

**My observations**

For $p=3:$

We have $S=\{a_1,\,  a_2,\, a_3,\, a_4\}$ and we need to show that for some distinct $a_1,a_2\in S$ we have
$$1 \cdot a_1 + 2 \cdot a_2 = 3 \cdot k,$$
for some integer $k$.  This is equivalent to
$a_1 - a_2 = 3(k-a_2), \, k-a_2 = \alpha, $ so $a_1 - a_2 = 3\alpha$.

And I don't know how to continue, could you help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for your question. Otherwise it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Comment: I first tried a few cases to know how the expression behaved. Then I looked for connections with other problems, I thought of Fermat's little theorem. My main problem is that I have no idea where to start.

Comment: @TomášMacháček You are supposed to put these thoughts/efforts in your post, instead of in the comment. Also for this one I would appreciate it if you could tell us the source of the problem.

Comment: It seems that I cannot construct counterexamples even with a set of $p$ elements, for $p > 3$.

Comment: @WhatsUp Here's one for you: $S=\{0,1,4,5,10\}$ for $p = 5$.

Comment: @player3236 Ah of course! It's $\{0, \dots, 0, 1, -1\}$ (mod $p$) in general. So the $p + 1$ in the question is tight.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't find the source.

Comment: I can't shake off the intuition that Pidgeonhole Principle is at play here...

Comment: That is same as Dirichlet's principle

Comment: @TomášMacháček The source is any indication of how you encountered this problem.  You either found it somewhere, or it was given to you by someone, or you invented it yourself.  It would be very odd if you were unable to identify which of these possibilities is true :).

Comment: I don't think this is true - if we choose the set $S$ to be distinct multiplies of $p$, then all such sets $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{p-1}\}$ work, no?

Comment: @JetChung "unique numbers" means that $a_1, \dots, a_{p - 1}$ are all pairwisely different. It doesn't mean that there is a unique choice of them.

Comment: @WhatsUp I have same opinion

Comment: "unique" is not a word whose meaning in entirely clear here "Distinct" is the common term for every pair being not equal. And note that while $=$ is transitive, $\ne$ is not. So saying $a_1 \ne a_2 \ne a_3$ only asures that $a_1 \ne a_2$ and $a_2 \ne a_3$. It does *not* imply that $a_1 \ne a_3$, though that was clearly the intention of the footnote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every choice of $p$ elements $x_0,\ldots,x_{p-1}\in S$ you have
$$k\sum x_i+\sum ix_i=\sum(i+k)x_i\equiv\sum ix_{i-k}\pmod{p},$$
if you consider the indices mod $p$. So it suffices to find $p$ such elements such that their sum is not divisible by $p$, i.e. their sum is a unit mod $p$, so that there exists an integer $k$ such that
$$k\sum x_i+\sum ix_i\equiv0\pmod{p}.$$
If the sum of *every* choice of $p$ elements is divisible by $p$, then all elements of $S$ are pairwise congruent mod $p$, so any choice of $p-1$ elements from $S$ will do as then
$$\sum ix_i\equiv x_1\sum i=x_1\frac{p(p+1)}{2}\equiv0\pmod{p}.$$

Comment: I don't understand the last row, is it the same as you factor out the $x_1$.

Comment: @TomášMacháček If all elements of $S$ are pairwise congruent mod $p$, then $x_i\equiv x_1\pmod{p}$, and then you can indeed factor out $x_1$, so the first congruence follows. I think the rest is clear?

Comment: But how do you know that $$k\sum x_i+\sum ix_i\equiv0\pmod{p}.$$

Comment: @TomášMacháček I claim that *if* the $x_i$ are not all pairwise congruent mod $p$, *then* for some choice of the $x_i$ you have $\sum x_i\not\equiv0\pmod{p}$, and *hence* there exists an integer $k$ satisfying that congruence.

Comment: I understand that it is possible to choose to select some elements of $x_i$, such that their sum is not divisible by $p$, but how can I prove that there exists $k$, such that $kx_0 + (k+1)x_1 + (k+2)x_2 + \cdots + (p-1 +k)x_{p-1}$ it is divisible by $p$.

Comment: If $\sum x_i\not\equiv0\pmod{p}$ then $\sum x_i$ is invertible mod $p$, and so $k\equiv-(\sum x_i)^{-1}\sum ix_i\pmod{p}$.

Comment: Thank you very much.